# hosting the application in iis cascading dropdown with ajax is display the method 500 error?

Tags: ajax, web-services, asmx, asp.net-4.0

I am using cascading dropdownExtender in my application it is working on local system but i am hosting IIS not working display the method 500 error what is the problem pls give me suggestion.

Thanku 
hemanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could findout my answer ,

first debugging the asmx page i could findout the duplication dlls in my application, i deleted that one it is working fine .

Answer (score 0):

In above question problem is first i hosted in iis that time the folder cascading drop down extender code dll is adding unfortunately i change the code paste  the dll so two dll are there in application in running time problem is occurred debugging the application i find out that error so be carefully to hoste the dlls .